# AWS の VPC へ VPN 接続したい

Tags: aws, network, vpn

手元の PC から、 AWS の VPC へ VPN 接続を行いたいです。具体的には:

- プライベート IP をブラウザで指定しながら、 VPC 内インスタンスのウェブサービスに接続したい。(インターネットに公開されないウェブサービス. もろもろ管理画面などを想定)

ssh + port forwarding で、特定のポートだけこじ開ける方法は分かりますが、それだと接続したサービスごとにポート・ホスト情報をひとつずつポートを開けていく必要があります。VPN 接続ができれば、そこの設定だけで、 VPC 内のインスタンスに IP 指定するだけで接続できるようになり、便利だと考えたので質問しています。

#### 質問

上記やりたいことを実現するのに利用できるツール・サービスなどはありますか？

[公式ページ: VPN 接続 - AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html) は見てみたのですが、何やらいろいろ書いてあるけれども結局上記やりたいことをどうやったらできるのかがパッと見わからないので質問しています。

#### 質問者の知識レベル

VPN という概念は知識として知っているが (LAN を拡張するような技術)、実際に VPN クライアントなどは触ったことがない。

#### 補足

1. 手元の PC だけから接続できればよく、手元の LAN を VPC と VPN 接続したいわけではありません。
2. ウェブブラウザが VPC 内部へ http(s) できればよいのか、について、今今のやりたいことを考えると、下記が達成できればそれでよいと考えます。

   - 「手元のPC」以外からは VPC 内部へ接続できない
   - 「手元のPC」はノートなので、違う LAN から接続しても、特に追加の設定変更は必要ない

Comment: 「手元の PC」は1台だけでよく、手元のサブネットをVPNにつなぐ必要はないですね？

Comment: @htb その通りです。補足を追記いたしました。

Comment: 「手元の PC」とありますが「プライベート IP をブラウザで指定しながら」ともあります。WebブラウザーがVPC内にHTTP/HTTPS接続できれば目的は達成できますか？

Comment: @sayuri 追記しました。 1. 「手元のPC」以外からは接続できない 2. 「手元のPC」が所属するネットワークに左右されない が実現できれば、目的は達成できます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ssh + port forwarding で、特定のポートだけこじ開ける方法は分かりますが、それだと接続したサービスごとにポート・ホスト情報をひとつずつポートを開けていく必要があります。

[OpenSSH](https://euske.github.io/openssh-jman/ssh.html)には `-D [address:]port` オプションがあります。

> 今のところ SOCKS4 および SOCKS5 プロトコルが使われており、ssh は SOCKS サーバのようにふるまいます。

また多くのWebブラウザーはSOCKSサーバーをproxyとして使用する機能があります。この２つを組み合わせることでVPNを使用しなくてもVPC内にアクセスできます。

- `ssh -D 1234`でVPC内のEC2に接続する
- Webブラウザーのproxy設定で`localhost:1234`を指定する
- WebブラウザーからVPC内のプライベートIPにアクセスする

Webブラウザーのみであればこの方法が簡単かと思います。

Comment: これを、 Chrome on Windows でやってみたのですが、この方法で作成した SOCK プロキシを設定したのですが、するとその他インターネットがつながらなくなって、おおぅ、となっている状態です。

Comment: @YukiInoue Chromeであれば起動オプションに`--proxy-server="socks://localhost:1234"`を指定してプロセスを分けたり、面倒であればFirefox等、ブラウザーを分けてしまってはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ブラウザ分割でひとまず、作業はできそうです。ありがとうございました。